# Halloween chess: Vampires and Zombies and Bats, oh my!

Tags: chess, seasonal

Halloween chess begins in the usual starting position, except most of the pieces are replaced with "fairy chess" pieces... or maybe we should say "ghoulish chess" pieces... The new types are:

- **Zombie pawn**:

  - It lumbers one step forward like a pawn (no initial double step).
  - If it winds up on the last rank, it does not promote, it just sits there and makes zombie noises.
  - Instead of capturing, it zombifies: it can transform an enemy piece sitting one step diagonally in front of it into a friendly zombie pawn
- **Zombie king**: similar idea. It lumbers one step in any direction like a king, but instead of capturing, it can zombify a piece one step away (even if on the first or last rank).
- **Vampire**:

  - It has a human form and a bat form
  - In human form, moves and captures like a queen.
  - In bat form, it moves like a knight but cannot capture, or be captured (or zombified).
  - Switching between forms uses up a move.

So, take the usual setup, replace the knights with vampires in bat form, the queen with a vampire in human form, the pawns with zombie pawns, and the king with a zombie king.

Winning is by checkmating the zombie king.

I'll let you play white. What's your move?

Hint 1:

> Isn't there something ... eerie ... about this game?

Hint 2:

> [short youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqBR8knRM2w)

Hint 3:

> Okay hint 2 wasn't actually helpful :-) Seriously though, isn't something wrong with this game?

Comment: Is a threat of zombification considered as a check? For example, what happens if a pawn moves forwards and is now diagonal to an enemy zombie king?

Comment: @Penguino - yes, that counts as check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I honestly have no idea what the question is asking, but I'd like to point out

> You can't lose! Since knights now cannot capture, walls are useful, and it is impossible to breach the wall that is the starting position. Anyone who comes close gets zombified, and if you capture a pawn near the king the king replaces it with a pawn.

Since I'm pretty bad at chess

> I'll aimlessly move a vampire in bat form back and forth until my opponent dies of boredom.

Comment: And yet you answered the question :-)